# SQL Server "CREATE CERTIFICATE" statement with Azure Key Vault

Tags: sql-server, azure-keyvault, azure-sql

Can the "CREATE CERTIFICATE" statement be used with Azure Key Vault instead of self-signed or from File?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't use CREATE CERTIFICATE with Key Vault.