# Retrieve password from Azure key vault in Azure Synapse T sql

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have created certificate in synapse with below code. I want to retrieve password from azure key vault and use the password in the below statement.

`CREATE CERTIFICATE ZZZZ_Certificate    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pGFD4bb925DGvbd2439587y'  WITH SUBJECT = 'ZZZ Information',    EXPIRY_DATE = '20221231';`

I went through MSFT document and did not find anything.  Is it possible to retrieve secret information from Azure key vault and use them in T SQL in synapse?

Regards,
Rajib

Answer (score 1):

`"I want to retrieve the password from Azure Key Vault and use it in the below statement.`

For the time being, you **can retrieve the credentials** from the Azure Key Vault but **not use them to generate a certificate.**

and here is the reference document for [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68302438/sql-server-create-certificate-statement-with-azure-key-vault).

```
I want to retrieve password from azure key vault and use the password in the below statement.
```

If you want to **retrieve credentials from the Azure Key Vault**, try to follow this [reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72692075/hide-and-retrieve-secret-keys-in-azure-synapse#:%7E:text=Yes,%20you%20can%20hide%20and%20retrieve%20secret%20keys,create%20a%20secret%20and%20store%20a%20secret%20value)
[image]
[image]
reference link for Use [Azure Key Vault secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities) in pipeline activities

Comment: Hi @vijaya,Thanks for your response.My requirement is to retrieve key vault infromatio  from synapse  T sql.Is it possible to retrieve from keyvault secret from T SQL Statement?

Comment: Hi @Rajib, My pleasure. As shown in synapse workspace image you can retrieve it but the problem is you want to use that password in Certificate. So that's what i am trying to say for the time being you can retrieve but not use them to generate a certificate.